# Showing divs in th on the same line

Tags: html, css

In my html-page I try to display a text and a button next to eachother in a table header:

```
<th>
<div class="thspan">text1</div>
<div class="bspan"><button class="buttoncss" id="text2"></button></div>
</th>
```

Using the following css code (rendered via stylus):

```
table th
  border 0px solid
  font 12px/1.3 "Lucida Grande", Arial, sans-serif
  font-weight bold
  padding-left 5px
  padding-right 5px
  background lightgrey
  clear both

.thspan
  display inline
  float left
  word-wrap break-word
  margin-right 25px

.bspan
  display inline
  float right
  width auto
```

Resulting in the following css-code:

```
table{border:1px solid;text-align:left}
table th{border:0 solid;font:12px/1.3 "Lucida Grande",Arial,sans-serif;font-weight:bold;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;background:#d3d3d3;clear:both}
table tr{border:1px solid;border-color:#000}
table td{white-space:nowrap;border:0 solid;font:12px/1.3 "Lucida Grande",Arial,sans-serifw;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px}
```

However the button shows on the following line. Any idea how this can be fixed?

Comment: You're missing all braces, colons and semi-colons.

Comment: Your code is full of mistakes! Correct them at first

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: The question says "(rendered via stylus)" [Stylus is yet another CSS preprocessor that attempts to rewrite the syntax for no good reason.](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus) Indeed, the given code snippet isn't CSS at all.

Comment: BoltClock is correct. It is rendered via Stylus, so the outcome will be normal css. That is not the use.

Comment: Oh, how nice. Does Stylus add random letters to keywords like sans-serif too?

Comment: He knows if his css works on the page, and you can check my answer I checked it and it works

Comment: @TheCodeBuccaneer Please post actual CSS in your questions here in the future. Thank you. Meanwhile, I've solved the problem, see my answer.

Comment: Added the css ouput. And while the code above is the input for stylus, it will be hard for stylus to add a random character. Removed the typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give class bspan from button to his div, and set width of that div to auto.

This is whole page

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<style>
    th
    {
      border: 0px solid;
      font :12px/1.3 "Lucida Grande", Arial, sans-serifw;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding-left: 5px;
      padding-right: 5px;
      background :lightgrey;
      clear :both;
    }
    .thspan
     { display: inline;
      float :left;
      word-wrap: break-word;
      margin-right: 6px;
    }
    .bspan
     { display: inline;
      float: right;
      width: auto;
    }
</style>
</head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <th>
                <div class="thspan">text1</div>
                <div class="bspan"><button  id="text2"></button></div>

            </th>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tried that with the following code:

<th>
<div class="thspan">text1</div>
<div class="bspan"><button class="buttoncss" id="text2"></button></div>
</th>


.thspan
  display inline
  float left
  word-wrap break-word
  margin-right 25px

.bspan
  display inline
  float right
  width auto

But that is not succesful

Comment: Yes, but it is still on the same line.

Comment: Well, I don't know then I'll edit it one more time and put the whole page here, I tried it in mozilla and in IE and it works

Comment: Your code examples works indeed, but when I implement it in my own table it doesn't seem to work. The issue is that in your example the with of the td is always 100%, but in my scenario the width of the th element will be limited by the values in the columns. For example if I add width: 50px; to the th-element in your example, the button will go to the next line.

Comment: I have it working in IE using:

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<style>
    th
    {
      border: 0px solid;
      font :12px/1.3 "Lucida Grande", Arial, sans-serifw;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding-left: 5px;
      padding-right: 5px;
      background :lightgrey;
      clear :both;
      width: 70px;
    }
    .thspan
     { display: inline;
      float :left;
      word-wrap: break-word;
      margin-right 25px;
    }

Comment: .bspan
     { display: inline;
      float: right;
      width: auto;
    }
</style>
</head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <th>
                <div class="bspan"><button  id="text2"></button></div>
                <div class="thspan">text1dskjsdkjfsd-sdfdsf</div>
            </th>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>

But now it doesn't work in Chrome and Firefox... Any idea why?

Comment: Continued question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128713/divs-on-same-line-in-tableheader-in

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to wrap button in div as it's unnecessary (unless you have a reason to do that)
The reason why it moves to new line is because you don;t apply styles to it.

```
<th> 
    <div class="thspan">text1</div> 
    <div class="myTestButton"><button class="bspan" id="text2"></button></div> 
</th>
```

CSS :

```
div.myTestButton
{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the `float` property. Check [here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Training/floating) for a good introduction.

Answer (score 0):

For one, you're not using the correct syntax on your css.

```
table th {
border: 0px solid;
font: 12px/1.3 "Lucida Grande", Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
background: lightgrey;
clear: both;
}

.thspan {
display: inline;
float: left;
word-wrap: break-word;
margin-right: 6px;
}

.bspan {
display: inline;
float: right;
width: 5px;
}
```

Try this, may work better.

Comment: The issue is not the syntax, it will be rendered correctly by stylus

Answer (score 0):

use `display : inline-table` for div and button

Comment: Updated (see post above), but not succesfull

Answer (score 0):

It's the `<th>`, which apparently tries to be as narrow as possible. Take the two divs out of the table, and it will work as expected. Or give the table and the th enough width. No need to change the css or the classes.

Comment: The <th> tries indeed to be as narrow as possible, therefore I use the margin-right to make room for the button. I can set the width of the th, because it will based on the content of the table.

Comment: That's a shame. Can't you give the th a `min-width` based on the widths of the text and the button?