# Divs on same line in tableheader in

Tags: html, css

The following code does the trick for showing two divs on the same line in Internet Explorer:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<style>
    th
    {
      border: 0px solid;
      font :12px/1.3 "Lucida Grande", Arial, sans-serifw;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding-left: 5px;
      padding-right: 5px;
      background :lightgrey;
      clear :both;
      width: 70px;
    }
    .thspan
     { display: inline;
      float :left;
      word-wrap: break-word;
      margin-right 25px;
    }
    .bspan
     { display: inline;
      float: right;
      width: auto;
    }
</style>
</head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <th>
                <div class="bspan"><button  id="text2"></button></div>
                <div class="thspan">text1dskjsdkjfsd-sdfdsf</div>
            </th>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

But now it doesn't work in Chrome and Firefox... Anyone an idea why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change the . thspan lie below

Add margin-right, get rid of the float and change display to block

```
.thspan {
        display: block;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that actually works :). Thanks. There is only one minor issue. In internet explorer the button will also have a margin to the right (only if the text is really long) of 20px (in chrome and firefox this is not the case). Any ideas what is causing that?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just that your 'th' isn't wide enough, try this:

```
th{
width: 160px;
}
```

Comment: That is correct, but the purpose of the css should be to display to wrapped text and button next to eachother when the width is limited.

Answer (score 0):

try using `display : inline-table` for the DIVs

Comment: Sorry, that is not solving the issue

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<style>
    th
    {
      border: 0px solid;
      font :12px/1.3 "Lucida Grande", Arial, sans-serifw;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding-left: 5px;
      padding-right: 5px;
      background :lightgrey;
      clear :both;
      width: auto;
      display: inline;
    }
    .thspan
     { display: inline;
      word-wrap: break-word;
      margin-right 25px;
    }
    .bspan
     { display: inline;
      width: auto;
    }
    #text2
    {
        display:inline;
    }
</style>
</head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <th>
                <div class="bspan"><button  id="text2"></button></div>
                <div class="thspan">text1dskjsdkjfsd-sdfdsf</div>
            </th>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can try this, and report back

Comment: iblazevic firstly thanks for all your effort! The above works indeed, only the th width will be set by the width of the value in the column underneath it, so I can not use auto for that.

Comment: no problem, maybe you'll help me next time, you can just check your questions as answered so they are not on the unanswered list anymore